# Tkinter._test() _tkinter.TclError

Tags: python, tkinter

on Linux Redhat 6, built and installed python2.7 from source so we would not interfere with the system python which is 2.66.

We have some scripts that use tkinter, so I ran the test and it fails. I see the popup window on a remote system but the popup is empty, no text or buttons are displayed.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Aug 21 2014, 16:37:19) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


>>> import Tkinter
>>> Tkinter._test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3778, in _test
label = Label(root, text=text)
File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2537, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2036, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf)) 
_tkinter.TclError
```

Comment: What is your question? You haven't asked anything.

Comment: Why am I getting a popup window with no widgets displayed? I get a window with no text and no buttons. The Tkinter._test() should display popup that has some text and a button, but I am getting just blank window.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tkinter._test()` checks that everything is okay.

Usually, if it brings an error, tkinter isn't properly installed, so install Python again, and also, make sure you don't tinker with the code of modules. That can be a problem too.
Re install it, basically.